How to design a flex PCB with 4 I2C sensors?
I am trying to design a 4 direction TOF array with a single I2C bus. The implementation will be on a flex PCB with the sensors being mounted on stiffeners.
Sensor : VL53L1
I will use the XSHUT pin on each of the sensors to write a unique address using an ESP32C3 each time the system is powered up. TUTORIAL
The pinout of the PCB end would be - 3.3V, SCL, SDA, XSHUT1-4, GND.

What are the PCB design requirements in such a design?
Will I have to add pull up resistors on each of the sensors for all the pins? (Except 3v3 and GND). The length of the PCB will be at max 25cm.

The main concern PCB-wise is that you stay within the maximum capacitance. You can use an online calculator to estimate the capacitance from the total run. A ground plane will increase noise immunity but also increase capacitance.
You only need one pull-up resistor for each of SDA and SCL. Usually they are placed near the I2C master.
XSHUT is a digital input for the sensor and you don't need a pullup resistor if you drive it with an MCU GPIO in Push-pull mode (the normal mode).
From this presentation are a couple slides showing the maximum capacitance for different I2C modes and bit rates. And also the resistor values which depend on the drive capability of the devices on the bus (all devices attached to the bus must be able to drive it, so the weakest one must be accommodated).

Higher capacitance means a lower pullup resistor value is required, but there is a minimum value the chip can reliably drive. Lower capacitance or lower speed means you can use higher values of pullup resistors, wasting less power.

Thank you for the valuable insight, I will have to check with the PCB fab house for the capacitance they add or go with the generic traces on a PCB with a ground and power plane will be about 1−3 pF/inch.

Careful- a 1mm wide trace on 25um polymide flex would be more like 100pF/inch over a ground plane, if my numbers are correct. 1.6mm PCBs are 64x thicker and similar epsilon-r so ..


Will I have to add pull-up resistors on each of the sensors for all the pins?

The datasheet answers your question. See page 6.



Thank you, I was initially thrown off with the readymade breakout boards which have around 10k pullups each. But on hindsight they might have been designed for use as a single device,
